# Sorting gridview using ado.net entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, entity-framework

i used below code to fill my gridview but i need sorting gridview . How can i do that in Ado.net enttiy framework? (Sorting gridview if  filling gridview with ado.net entity  )

```
  void LoadStaffPersonel()
        {
            int selectedDepartman = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["SelectedDepartmanID"]);
            string name = "";
            using (staffContext = new StaffManagementEntities())
            {
 name = staffContext.Departman.Where(d => d.ID == selectedDepartman).First().Name;


                ObjectResult<StaffsPersonel> personalData = staffContext.GetPersonelData(name);
                gvPersonel.DataSource = personalData.ToList();
                gvPersonel.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use an "EntityDataSource" on your page, and use it to provide sorting and paging. See the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.entitydatasource.aspx) for more details.

If you "materialize" your list of data by issuing a .ToList() call, you lose all those capabilities.